# Why is `this` sometimes undefined inside an object literal?

Tags: javascript

**Browser Error**

- TypeError: this is undefined

**Related Code**

```
// start of module

$A.module({
    Name: 'MUserNew',
```

...

```
    enter: (function (event) {
        var pipe = {};
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            pipe = $A.definePipe(this.Name); // **fail here**
            $A.machine(pipe);
        }
    }).bind(this),
```

...

```
        // inside module as well
        this.E.un_go.addEventListener("keypress", 
                                       this.enterB, 
                                       false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the right thing by using `.bind()`, but unfortunately `this` does not have the behavior you expect. It does not take on the value of an "in progress" object inside an object literal.  You have to make the object, set the handler, and then pass it to your "module" method.

You can still do it in one expression, like this:

```
$A.module(function() {
  var obj = {
    // ... 
    enterB: function(event) { ... },
    // ...
  };
  obj.enterB = obj.enterB.bind(obj);
  return obj;
}());
```

Comment: @pure_code I just updated the answer, anticipating that objection :-)

Comment: @pure_code That code will pass an object to your function - look at it closely. What's passed to the "module" function is the result of **calling** that anonymous function.  The anonymous function creates the object and returns it.  It is not possible for the "method" function to tell how the object passed to it was created, in any case.

Comment: It is a function expression.  Normally you see them parenthesized (like `(function() { ... })()` or something similar), but that's only really necessary when your function expression is the **start** of a statement. In this case, it's not; however if you want to you can enclose it in parentheses. They won't hurt anything :-)

Comment: @pure_code No - inside the anonymous function, you'll bind it to the object variable that's created.  That's why I pass "obj" as the argument to `.bind()`

Comment: @pure_code oh right - well it depends on where the code is running, but yes it's either the global object or else whatever `this` is where that "$A.module()" call is running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bind(this)` inside a function definition, were `this` will be defined (not undefined).  The function needs to be called.

```
/*MUserNew
**
**
**            
*/
$A.module({
    Name: 'MUserNew',
    // ....
    init: function () {
        this.enter = this.enter.bind(this);
```

Comment: Yes that will work just fine if your "module" code calls the "init" function!